# Android - Same core features for multiple applications

Tags: android, gradle, build, release

I'm currently developing an Android app that needs to be distributed as separated apk to the store for n customers. All having same features, only the design differs or text sometimes.

How would you manage this? Which best practices would you recommend? I can definitely start from scratch again. It's a side project, so best practices first :)

Comment: If the changes are mostly cosmetic, with little to no Java code changes, product flavors (as others have mentioned) are a great choice. If, OTOH, you anticipate non-trivial Java changes, you could consider a library module containing the common stuff, with separate app modules that depend upon the library for different customers. The techniques can be combined as well: have app modules for different groups of customers need the same functionality changes, using flavors for each customer and using the library module for cross-app common code and resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Flavors, For complete detail you can refer [this Official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors).

Comment: you can define a different package for each flavor in the app build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need **flavors**. You can define for each flavor different versions of the files that vary either code or resources.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html